# Representing dataset with long field name using graduated color?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I have some questions on symbology of dataset.

I have 47 recordset ranging from -1 to 10. And some of value have zero.

[image]

And I want to represent my dataset with graduated color. It usually works well.

But something weird this time. Different graduated color representation is showing whenever i regenerate the dataset.

So map is changing everytime I have clicked the button on the map and It is closing suddenly.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Why does it happen?

Comment: What software are you using to view this in? Can you grab a screen shot of your symbol dialog please and include that in your question.

Comment: I used Arcgis 10.1. I have uploaded.

Comment: The screen shots show some differences but the classification doesn't change, I was after a screen shot of the symbology tab of the feature layer mhw47DBLink, is the layer attribute joined? if so is the symbology from the joined attributes?

Comment: Sure I have joined the dataset with 47 polygon geomap. And divide the ranges. 
Every map on this article is the result of one column 'DRSSL1TR85_32'.
And as you announed eariler, it shows different result everytime. 
and the label is the value of 'DRSSL1TR85_32'.

Strange. It was the first time I have experiend this error. Strange. 
I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Save your joined layer as a new shapefile or a feature class into geodatabase to make your join permanent and see if that can solve the problem. If you save your data as shapefile the field names will be truncated because the number of characters are 10 so it is better to define short names but you don't have such limitation if the feature class is saved in File geodatabase.

Comment: Maybe they overlap? Intersect with single input to check.

Comment: Thank you !~ ahmadhanb ! I will try. And I will get back to you with update.
Thank you !~ FlelixIP. Those polygons are not overlapped. but I will recheck with dataset again.

Comment: The length of column name was the reason of error. After I export the linked shape file with DB, they truncated the whole name. Thank you for all. !~ I find out what was the reason of the problem and fixed result from changed name. 
Mr. Michael Stimson, Mr. ahmadhanb, and Mr. FelixIP ! Thank you again. I am attaching final result above.

Comment: It is better to post the solution as an answer to answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MichaelStimson, @ahmadhanb, and @FelixIP helped find the solution.

The length of column name was the reason of error.

After I export the linked shape file with DB, they truncated the name. I found out what was the reason of the problem and attained fixed result from the shape file with changed name. I am attaching final result.

1. truncated name of dataset column. 
   [image]
2. Final fixed result. 
   [image]